# Is "then" correct here? To mean "in that case"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

A woman is yelling at her boyfriend over something. When she finally stops, he says -

Boyfriend: Can we watch a movie now?

Woman: Sure. I'll try to be quiet then.

My question is if the ***then*** at the end of the woman's line of dialog would be completely idiomatic? To mean "in that case"? Could it be misunderstood to mean something else?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's a perfectly valid sentence.

And yes, there's a small ambiguity. "Then" can mean "in that case". Like, "If you complete this project on time, then you will get a bonus." "Then" can also refer to a point in time. Like, "My boss yelled at me. I quit right then."

So in this case, she might mean, "If we watch TV, then I'll be quiet." Or she might mean, "If we watch TV, at the time that we are watching TV I will be quiet."

In this case, while the two interpretations are technically different, the basic meaning of the statement is the same either way, so it doesn't match matter. If you thought about it perhaps you could come up with an example where these two definitions of "then" could create a real ambiguity. I can't think of such an example off the top of my head, but whatever.

Comment: A downvote with no explanation? :'(

Comment: @gotube Yeah, I'm not going to roll into a ball and cry because someone downvoted my answer, but a downvote with no explanation isn't very helpful. If it's wrong, what's wrong and what is the correct answer? Or if it's unclear, what don't you understand? Etc. I'm sorry, I have to stop typing because I can't see the keyboard through my tears ...